# how to get calendars shared with logged in user using Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

With following code I get events from logged-in user's calendar with delegated permissions.

```
var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();
var events = await graphClient.Me.Events.Request().GetAsync();
```

**My question is**

How can I get list of calendars (at least a specific calendar or both even better) someone shared with this user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve a list of calendars:

```
var calendars = await graphClient
  .Me
  .Calendars
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();
```

This will return a collection of `Calendar` objects. You can determine if a given calendar was shared with the current user by looking at the `owner` property. Any calendar owner that doesn't match the current user is a calendar that has been shared with them.